# How can I get only the date and time from the string?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 I have:

```
satelliteMapToRead = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "satelliteMap.txt");
```

Then in the constructor:

```
ExtractImages.ExtractDateTime("image2.ashx?region=eu&time=", "&ir=true", satelliteMapToRead);
```

Then in the ExtractImages class i have:

```
public static void ExtractDateTime(string firstTag, string lastTag, string f)
{
    int index = 0;
    int t = f.IndexOf(firstTag, index);
    int g = f.IndexOf(lastTag, index);
    string a = f.Substring(t, g - t);
}
```

This an example of a string in the text file:

> image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309202145&ir=true

From this string i want that the variable g will contain only: 201309202145
And then to convert the variable a to date time : date 2013 09 20 - time 21 45

What I get in the variable a now is:

> image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309202215

And it's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for the length of `firstTag`:

```
int t = f.IndexOf(firstTag, index) + firstTag.Length;
```

Comment: Ed this is working indeed: int index = 0;
            int t = f.IndexOf(firstTag, index) + firstTag.Length;
            int g = f.IndexOf(lastTag, index);
            string a = f.Substring(t, g - t);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already doing it this way, juts use `indexOf("time=")` again to get `201309202215`. Then the date/time is given by

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Zong Zheng i did : DateTime dt =  DateTime.ParseExact(a, "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  The variable a now contain 201309202215 but im getting an error/exception: FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Switch this line to:

```
int t = f.IndexOf(firstTag, index) + firstTag.Length;
```

`IndexOf` returns the position of the first character of your string. So in your example, `t` is actually zero. This is why `a` also has the first tag in it.

Comment: Omada using your line now the variable a contain: 201309202215&ir=true","/image2.ashx?reg

Answer (score 0):

Without error handling (missing parameters or invalid format):

```
string url = "image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201309202145&ir=true";
var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(queryString["time"], "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```